# Solr - Indexing data after transforming database data

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have around 30 million unique IDs stored in a database.
In addition, I have some logic defined on my local machine which uses these unique IDs to generate a description for these IDs.

Using Solr, I want to index the description and store the IDs (so that when a user searches for the description keywords, he is returned the unique ID(s))

I came across the DataImportHandler, and from what I infer, I can't use it since my data from the database needs to be transformed before indexing.

The other problem is that my database is single-threaded, so I don't want to keep a connection open for a long time (since that would put other users' queries on hold).

My current approach is that, I retrieve 1000 records, transform them and batch index them using SolrJ. This takes >5 hours to index the entire data.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: The answer of Persimmonium will help you for the bigger part of your problem. But about your database, what DBMS do you use? Probably that problem is better of in an own question. It is not good to ask too many questions in one go here ...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using DIH: I think you can do it, you have two possible places to do your transformation:

1. UpdateRequestProcessor: this allows you to transform the doc before it is indexed, no matter where it comes from into solr. See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor)
2. use a [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) in DIH, you can use a variety of scripting languages to transform the data.

Regarding not holding up other users of you db...that sounds a problem, I guess you could just create a second db server to serve as solr source (if it has native replication that would be even easier)?